# Reset radio button and checkbox value in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of radio buttons and one of them is checked like this.

```
<input name="test_data" type="radio" value='1' id="test_data">
<input name="test_data" type="radio" value='2' id="test_data" checked="checked">
<input name="test_data" type="radio" value='3' id="test_data">
<input name="test_data" type="radio" value='4' id="test_data">
```

I have a link like this

```
<a href="#" id="resetvalue">reset value</a>
```

How can I reset the radio button value when the user clicks on the `resetvalue` id. I am not using any form.
If there is a form and button we can easily do for that using reset property.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

**jQuery**

```
$('#resetvalue').click(function() {
  $('input[name="test_data"]:nth-of-type(2)').prop('checked', true);
});
```

This resets the radio button back to the second value using the [`:nth-of-type()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vLmt3L5/9/)**

Comment: Might want to add this `$('input[value="2"]').prop('checked', true);` to "reset" it back to the original

Comment: my problem is when I click the resetvalue I need to go to previous value that is the second item should be checked.

Comment: @samunp, updated. Should work properly now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it https://jsfiddle.net/0vLmt3L5/7/

```
$('#resetvalue').click(function() {
  $('input[value="2"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

This will set it back to the original checked radio button, and yes I took Hunter's fiddle and just added

this:`$('input[value="2"]').prop('checked', true);`

instead of this: `$('input[name="test_data"]').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#resetvalue").on("click",function(e){

    $("input[type='radio']").removeAttr("checked");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( '#resetvalue' ).click(function() {
    $( '[name="test_data"].checked' ).prop('checked', false);
    // Set eq from 0 (first radio) to value you want
    $( '[name="test_data"]' ).eq(0).prop('checked', true);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="test_data" type="radio" value='1' id="test_data">
    <input name="test_data" type="radio" value='2' id="test_data" checked="checked">
    <input name="test_data" type="radio" value='3' id="test_data">
    <input name="test_data" type="radio" value='4' id="test_data">

<a href="#" id="resetvalue">Reset</a>
```